# jQuery wrap div with form without submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<button id="my_button">Test</button>
```

Javascript (jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#my_button').click(function () {
    $(this).wrap('<form>')
  })
})
```

And when there's a click on the button it's wrap it with the form as I wished but also submit the form.

I want just to wrap with the form without submitting it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either add a call to `preventDefault`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#my_button').click(function(e) {
    // Accept the arg -------------^
        e.preventDefault();      // Prevent the default action
        $(this).wrap('<form>')
    });
});
```

...or change the type of the button to `button`:

```
<button type="button" id="my_button">Test</button>
```

...since the default `type` of `button` is `submit`.

Comment: Thanks,  for the case of <input type="image" /> I should use the preventDefault()?

Comment: @OmerNizri: Yes, those also submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `type` attribute with a value `button` to convert it into a simple button otherwise which acts as a `submit` button.

```
<button type="button" id="my_button">Test</button>
```

Comment: does this actually solve the problem, or should this have been a comment?

Comment: @TimothyGroote: Yes, this solves the problem. The default `type` of `button` is `submit`. By changing it to `button`, it no longer submits the form.